# Change font inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have a HTML page that have an `iframe`. I want to change style of iframe content but I don't seem to be able to do so.

I want to change the font of all content inside the `iframe` to "Tahoma". This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>

<title>phpinfo()</title>
<style type="text/css">
#outerdiv
{
width:446px;
height:246px;
overflow:hidden;
position:relative;
}

#inneriframe
{
position:absolute;
top: -508px;
left: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 615px;
font-family: Tahoma;
}
</style>

<script>
onload = function()
{
 document.frm.document.body.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id='outerdiv '>
<iframe  name="iframe" src="http://m.sarafikish.com" id='inneriframe' name="frm" scrolling=no frameborder="0"  > </iframe>
</div>    
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 12):

This is only possible if the `iframe`'s `src` is set to a page on the same domain or otherwise satisfies the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). Your question does not specify if you meet these requirements, but if you do, you can use the [`contentDocument` property of the iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) to manipulate the iframe through JavaScript.

**Example:**

```
document.getElementById("inneriframe").contentDocument.body.style.fontFamily = "Tahoma";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var frame = $('#frameId');
frame.load(function () {
    frame.contents().find('body').css('font-family', 'Arial');
}
```

If you want to use custom font:

```
var frame = $('#frameId');
frame.load(function () {
    var head = frame.contents().find('head');
    $('<link/>', {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        type: "text/css",
        href: "/url/to/style_with_fonts.css"
    }).appendTo(head);
    frame.contents().find('body').css('font-family', 'Custom Font');
}
```