# how to change font in **tradingview** library with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fonts, tradingview-api

I want to change tradingview `font-family`  in vue.js codes

use below code in css file , but does not work

```css
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'irsans';
      src: url('./../assets/fonts/iransansweb.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('./../assets/fonts/iransansweb.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('./../assets/fonts/iransansweb.woff') format('woff'),
        url('./../assets/fonts/iransansweb.woff2') format('woff2')
    }
    * { font-family: 'irsans' !important; }
    body {
      font-family: 'irsans' !important;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: we can´t tell if the path to the ressources is correct, can you verify that they get loaded? (check network tab probably)

Comment: path resource is corrected ,becoz working  in all elements in my page ,but not affect in tradingview control

Comment: okay, it´s because of the iframe, afaik you could only change it if its on the same domain https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963616/change-font-inside-an-iframe